# Is there a lower bound for the maximal number of separated sets?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $T\colon X\to X$ uniformly continuous. A set $E\subset X$ is said to be $(n,\varepsilon)$-separated if for any distinct $x,y\in E$ there is a $0\leq j< n$ such that $d(T^j(x),T^j(y))>\varepsilon$.

For a compact set $K\subset X$ let $s_n(\varepsilon,K)$ denote the largest cardinality of any $(n,\varepsilon)$-separated set $E$ contained in $K$.

---

Is there a lower bound for $s_n(\varepsilon,K)$?

Doesn't from the definition follow, that $s_n(\varepsilon,K)\geq 2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically related to the hausdorff measure of $K$.

For any $\varepsilon >0$ there is $\varepsilon>\delta(\varepsilon)>0$ such that 
$d(x,y)\leq \delta$ implies $d(Tx,Ty)<\varepsilon$

Let $\delta^j(\varepsilon)=\delta(\delta(\delta(....\delta(\varepsilon))$ $j$-times.

Thus, if $d(x,y)\leq \delta^j(\varepsilon)$ then $x,y$ are not $(j,\varepsilon)$-separated.

It folows that if a subset of $K$ is $(n,\varepsilon)$-separated, then it is a $\delta(\varepsilon)^n$-packing (according to the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delone_set) definition)

In particular if a subset of $K$ is a maximal $\delta^n(\varepsilon)$-packing
then it is a $\delta^n(\varepsilon)$-net.

Thus you get estimate on the cardinality depending on the [Hausdorff measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_measure) of $K$.

Comment: by the way, this also depends on $T$. If for instance $T$ is a constant map, then $S_n(\varepsilon,K)=1$ for any $n,\varepsilon,K$.

Comment: Isn't always $s_n(\varepsilon,K)\geqslant 1$?

Comment: it is a cardinality, so it is a positive number hence $\geq 1$. If $T$ is constant you have no two points that are $(n,\varepsilon)$-separated, thus it is $1$.

Comment: If its a cardinality it cannot be 0?